# Rails Haml - end if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I need to switch forms declaration in HAML.

```
- if params[:action] == 'tomato'
  = form_for @request, :url => 'request/tomato' do |f|
- else
  = form_for @request do |f|

    = f.text_field ...  # form content

  = f.text_field # don't work too
```

But i can't use `end` to separate form declaration from form content, so i get 500 internal server error

How can i achieve this?

Comment: @Awea i tried both variants, i think haml don't know where the `if` statement ends and in first case don't see form content

Comment: the second text_field need to be in both form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
- args = params[:action] == "tomato" ? {:url => 'request/tomato'} : {}
= form_for @request, args do |f|
  = f.text_field :field_one
  = f.text_field :field_two
```

Comment: nice but your indentation is all wrong too - the third and fourth lines are indented by more than 2 spaces

Comment: @stephenmurdoch he may be using tabs instead of spaces

Comment: soft tabs are always better ^^

Comment: I had much the same method -- won't post since it's so similar, but here was my reasoning to go with this method: You need to keep your parent (form) and child (text_files) in the same scope. Haml will auto-close if's for you, and your forms as well, so your tomato param will never get a text_field in your example

Comment: I copied from the OP's post. I used 2 spaces, he was using tabs

Answer (score 2):

Since Haml works on indentation, you don't need an End statment after an If.

Make sure your 'if' and 'else' are aligned and put any content that should come after at the correct indentation.